# Hosting server for websockets

Tags: python, websocket

I've been trying to get this chat to run online so other computers aside from mine can use it however I'm totally lost on how to even begin. I've visited web services like node.js and socket.io but personally I'd like to avoid having re-write my coding plus I'd like control over the server myself as it would be more of a learning experience.

So far my only trail is to purchase a vps(perhaps https://aws.amazon.com/free/ or https://www.tilaa.com/) but I'm unsure as to how I would host my chat on this vps and the level of difficulty i may have to face.

So is there anyway I can host a websocket chat for other computers to connect to?

Comment: "So is there anyway I can host a websocket chat for other computers to connect to?"  yeah, use "openshift" or "koding" for hosting python scripts  and you can install required python packages for your app .

Comment: You might find some answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402332/host-a-python-based-websocket-server